# Selenium cannot enable javascript in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

how do I enable javascript in selenium using python? I tried several methods but mine isnt working. Does anyone know how could i fix this issue? Thanks

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
import urllib.request
import string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

Error i got

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_argument'
  File "C:\Users\bustillo-ronald\Desktop\python-basics\Scrape\propertyguru.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a `ChromeOptions` object first and `add_argument` to that. Then pass the `options` object as an argument to the `Chrome` webdriver.

something like this

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

# Now back to your code
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=options)

...
```

Comment: i already did like this sir `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
opt.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path,chrome_options=opt)` But the site that i want to scrape doesnt let me to access because javascript is disabled

Comment: the site says cant identify my browser. its because javascript or cookies are disabled. how to prevent this sir?

Comment: How is the site indicating this to you?

Comment: when i run my code then the browser says cant identify my browser because of disabled javascript

Comment: What happens if you run this: ```driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-javascript-enabled")
assert(driver.find_element_by_id("detected_value").text=="Yes")```

Comment: I mean to verify that you have javascript enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203007/discussion-between-vince-and-mslimmer).